# PHP PDO upload image to DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP with PDO to connect DB.

```
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();
```

How to edit below code to connect DB?

```
    if($file_size < 60000){
if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $location)){
try{
***$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `file`(file_name, file_type, date_uploaded, location) VALUES ('$file_name', '$file_type', '$date_uploaded', '$location')";
$conn->exec($sql);***
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}

***$conn = null;***
header('location: home.php');
}
</center>";
}
```

Comment: What is your question again? How to store an image? How to run a query? How to connect with PDO? How to use an existing $pdo variable instead of nonexistent $conn?

Comment: Connect to MySQL using PDO function: pdo_connect_mysql(). So, I cannot remove $pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();

Comment: then, why your question is titled *PHP PDO upload image to DB*?

Comment: do you understand that your pdo connection is stored in the $pdo variable but for some reason you are trying to use $conn?

Answer (score -1):

HI you should use something like:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

please check https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php